# How does .ToString() on a boxed object work?

Tags: c#, clr, tostring, boxing

Imagine the following example:

```
class foobar
{
    string b = string.Empty;
    public foobar(string abc)
    {
        b = abc;    
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return b;
    }
}
```

I could use it like this:

```
void Main()
{
    foobar test = new foobar("test string");
    Console.WriteLine(test);
}
```

With the expected output of `test string`

What if I do something like this?

```
void Main()
{
    object test2 = (object)new foobar("test string 2");
    Console.WriteLine (test2);
}
```

I still get the output `test string 2` even though I boxed my class inside object.

It even works when I use an object returned by a method:

```
private object DoSomething()
{
    return (object) new foobar("test3..");
}
```

How does the CLR know which type my object is was and where to look for the .ToString() implementation?

Does this even work when used accross assembly boundaries?

Comment: Every `object` implements (or overrides) a `ToString` method, so it can get the method using reflection.

Comment: Casting your type to `object` isn't actually boxing it. Boxing only occurs on _value_ types. All you are doing here is referring to your object via the `object` variable type. Inheritance will still function normally in this instance, finding your overridden method.

Comment: Is this really reflection? What happens if I am using it across assemblies where the receiving assembly has no way to know which (custom) type is contained in the object?

Comment: @Romoku It doesn't use reflection. Every type inherits from `object` so they all inherit the methods defined on `object`.

Comment: @buddybubble Even in separate assemblies, the type information is known either at compile-time via references, or run-time via late binding / dynamic loading.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth The CLR still needs to lookup the `ToString` implementation from the method tables.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth: Ah ok! Is there any situation where this will not work? Or rephrased: If if override ToString on my class, can I be sure that it will be called everytime a string representation of an instance of my class is needed, even if this instance is inside an object or moved across assemblies?

Comment: @Romoku Yes but that isn't reflection, that's a virtual method lookup.

Comment: @buddybubble Yes you can be sure. The only time inheritance chains are broken is when people "hide" members using the `new` syntax, instead of `virtual` and `override`.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Reflection is looking up the metadata, so I don't see the difference between "method table lookup" and "reflection."

Comment: @Romoku Reflection as a topic in .NET is quite different to what the CLR is doing under the hood and you are confusing the terminology, this is why it is different.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Doesn't the CLR consume the same metadata it facilitates access to?

Comment: @Romoku You could make the argument that any action looking at meta-data is reflection, but then the compiler is just one giant meta-data emitter. Reflection as a coding topic is quite separated from the CLR in C#, it's just a butch of types under a namespace that allows you to programmatically understand assembly meta-data, it doesn't tell you what method will be called when a method is asked for in a type hierarchy. This is all just confusing the question at any rate.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Well I thought buddybubble was asking about the CLR, so I was thinking in terms of the CLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ToString()` is visible on and accessible via Object.

Providing an overridden implementation of a method and having it called when the object is accessed as its ancestor or a base class is a core requirement and benefit of polymorphism.

Specifying an override tells the object's metadata to remap calls to the ancestor's `ToString()` method to the new one, even if that object is accessed as though it were its ancestor.